# What does "Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number..." mean exactly?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to create a line chart from data that I have in a .csv file. I used an example I found online, but I am getting an error: "Error:  attribute d: Expected number," Im not sure exactly what that means or what I have to fix in my code.

this is the code that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Arduino Server</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--div that will contain everything-->
    <div class ="container">

        <div>
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color:red;">My Arduino 
Server</h1>
        </div>

        <!--div that will contain the Temperature Link-->
        <div >
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #ff6961">Temperature Over 
              Some Time</h1>    
            <script>
                // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
                var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                // parse the date / time
                var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

                // set the ranges
                var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
                var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

                // define the line
                var line = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temp); });

                // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
                // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
                // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform",
                          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + 
                           ")");

                // Get the data
                d3.csv("p.csv", function(error, data) {
                  if (error) throw error; 

                  // format the data
                  data.forEach(function(d) {
                      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
                      d.temp = +d.temp;
                  });

                  // Scale the range of the data
                  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
                  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.temp; })]);


                  // Add the X Axis
                  svg.append("g")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

                  // Add the Y Axis
                  svg.append("g")
                      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

                                      // Add the valueline path.
                  svg.append("path")
                      .data([data])
                      .attr("class", "line")
                      .attr("d", line);

                });
            </script>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of the data that I am trying to graph:

```
date,temp
1-Apr-17,70
2-Apr-17,80
3-Apr-17,75
4-Apr-17,64
5-Apr-17,54
6-Apr-17,67
7-Apr-17,89
8-Apr-17,87
9-Apr-17,25
10-Apr-17,56
```

How can I better understand the error?

Comment: What line does the error fire on?

Comment: I think the error comes from the `.attr("d", line);` which is expecting a number. Probably comes from the date.

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any error and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/gcs20z8a/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, i noticed that you added this line of code `var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());` , what exactly is that for? Is it just parsing the csv to be read as a text file? strangely, my code wasnt working yesteray, but it is today, except it does not update if i change the values. Any idea of what it could be? thank you for your help!

Comment: I forgot to mention, if i replace my code with yours, it does not work. I get an error saying: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null` I'm not sure why it would be null?

Comment: I cant't possibly know what you mean by *if I replace my code with yours*. That line you asked is simply a substitute for the CSV, since I cannot upload a real CSV in JsFiddle.